# How to connect a distributed database in a web application?

Tags: database, jsp, servlets, database-schema

I plan to use a distributed database but my question is what if you can use the database schema distributed in a web application? , In specific with Java (Servlets, JSP).

Watch what happens I plan to do a small control system for a cinema with multiple branches, where the user may buy ticket to a function, the system I want to use a distributed database but do not know if my idea is possible?.

Comment: can you be more elaborate on the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to simply use a centralized database. Why is this not an option?

Another option is to use a database at each location, and have them synchronize to a central database (master-slave), or with each other (master-master). Look at replication for your database of choice, or db sync tools like SymmetricDS.